# Can't use Java 20.0.1 and Gradle 7.5 to import Gradle project android

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I reinstalled Android Studio and flutter. Now when I create new project in vs code i am getting error Can't use Java 20.0.1 and Gradle 7.5 to import Gradle project android.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS1be.png)

Comment: Please use the Java version that is included in Android Studio, at the moment this is Java 17. Anyway using non-LTS versions is IMHO a bad idea. The only thing you can get from a new version is a headache because of incompatibilities.